# SDN 3.3.0 with CDI; Maven Clean Install Returns: Can't work with a null graph database

Tags: java, cdi, spring-data-neo4j

I have tried to work with SDN 3.3.0 to get a graphdatabase, which i want to provide via cdi to use it without the complete Spring-Framework.

If I use SDN 3.1.2 the Graphdatabase, all things works with a SpringRestGraphDatabase Object fine.
Now I add SDN 3.3.0 to get a TransactionManager which can commit my REST-Requests.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

A Maven clean install works fine at the moment, but later it gave me this Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can't work with a null graph database

This is my Code to Provide the GraphDatabase:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Neo4jConfigurationProvider {

@Resource(lookup = "rest/neo4j")
private String baseUriString;

@Inject @LIFE Logger logger;

private SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase graphDatabase;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    checkNotNull(baseUriString);
    graphDatabase = new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase(baseUriString);
    checkNotNull(graphDatabase);
}

@Produces
@Singleton
public GraphDatabase graphDatabase() {
    return graphDatabase;
}

@TXM
@Produces
public TransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return graphDatabase.getTransactionManager();
}
}
```

Usage:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {...}
```

...
In my PersonResource Class:

```
@Inject PersonRepository;
```

I don't know how i can fix this temporary bug.
It would be nice if anybody could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue in JNDI Resource injection. Basically Resource is an EJB annotation and your configuration is plain CDI bean. Try to annotate configuration with @Singelton from EJB.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work assuming you've the a local instance running and you're using spring boot.

```
    package com.example.analytics.config;


    import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Properties;

    @EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.analytics.repository")
    @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.analytics.config")
public class SpringBootConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootConfiguration.class);


    /**
     * Constructor that sets the package for domain entities
     */
    public SpringBootConfiguration() {
        LOG.debug("Creating SpringBootConfiguration ...");
        setBasePackage("com.example.analytics.model");
    }


    /**
     * Connect to the remote instance of Neo4j through its REST interface
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("databaseConnectionProperties")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() throws IOException {
        LOG.debug("Creating the graph database service ...");

        final SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase graphDatabase = new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/", "neo4j", "password");

        LOG.debug("Graph database instance has been created!");

        return graphDatabase;
    }



    @PostConstruct
    public void uponConstruction() {
        LOG.debug("Construction of the class {} has been completed!", this.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```